# How to run a PL/pgSQL procedure when an user connects to PostgreSQL DB?

Tags: postgresql, trigger, plpgsql

I am creating a software for parking slots reservations in parking buildings. One requirement is to whenever an user logs into the app, his Public IP address should be stored along with his user name and date.

I've created a PL/pgSQL procedure that successfully stores such info on a table, but now I am wondering how to execute that procedure whenever an user connects to the DB? Is there some way to create a Trigger on some Postgres table to do it safely?

Comment: There are no login triggers in PostgreSQL. You could look at [this extension](https://github.com/splendiddata/login_hook).